# Google Map API, can't get name of a place

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to do a little project using the Google Map API and my problem is that I do not find how to get the name of a place on the Map when I click on it. By place I mean the things represented as a circle with a picture inside (museum, restaurant, monuments, etc.)
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uft6.png)

In this picture, the default action of the map is to open an info-windows when I click on it, with the name of the place, that's exactly what I want BUT I have no solution to "extract" the name (To use it somewhere else) because this is a default reaction...

I've tried to get it with the following code :

```js
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    getAddress(event.latLng);
});

function getAddress(latLng) {
    geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
    function(results, status) {
        if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var arrayLength = results.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                var request = {
                    placeId: results[i].place_id_id
                };
                service.getDetails(request, callback);
            }
        }
    });
}

function callback(place, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log(place);
    }
}
```

But the only precised thing returned is the address (in the example : "37 Phillip St, Sydney NSW 2000, Australie") but never the name of the place.

And I've really found nothing on Google, seems really weird...

Answer (score 2):

As per the code you have provided, you are using the `PlaceDetails` from which you can actually already get the data you need. As per the [Places Details Results docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_results):

> A successful getDetails() call returns a `PlaceResult` object.

Wherein `PlaceResult` object pretty much has the info that you might need. Haven't tested it out, but it has the `address_components` property that has a structure like so (referred to [Geocoder response sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses)  on this one):

```
"address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
```

and also the `name` property which is simply described in the docs as:

> The place's name.

Just tweak around the results of the PlaceDetails request and I'm pretty sure you'll find it.